# iTunesConnect app primary language change not propagating

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My iOS application's primary language was English. The application is Ready for Sale. Now I changed the primary language to Turkish approximately 24 hours ago. I searched Google, however it still shows the English meta data.
You can find the app [here](https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/aerobilet-flights-hotels-transfers/id570990761?mt=8).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did it change after all?

Answer (score 0):

This was likely caused by the fact that Google's Web Crawlers haven't run yet. What this means is that even tough your app is already in Turkish, Google still shows results from before you updated the app. When you download the app it will be in Turkish by default, if there is a Turkish localization of it. For the Google results you should just wait some time until the Itunes pages are crawled again.

Hope that helps, Julian